# Uncountables sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $Z=\{A\subseteq \mathbb N\mid A\sim \mathbb N\}$ is a uncountable set.

We reasons by absurdity and assume that $Z$ is countable. So is $Z$ is finite or $Z$ is countable. It clearly cannot be finite. If it is countable then $$Z=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots\}$$  I try to use the Cantor diagonal to arrive at an absurdity, how I can use it in this case?

Comment: In your definition of set $Z,$ "$A\sim \mathbb N$" is supposed to be a true/false statement about $A$ (thereby giving a criteria for $A$ to be a member of $Z),$ but it's not. Thus you have not defined $Z$ as a set. I can guess what you probably intend, but for practice I recommend you try to fix this.

Comment: **Hint :** $Z$ is exactly the set of all infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, so its complement in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which is countable.

Comment: You are using "countable"  with two different  meanings.